# Change Chrome Omnibox Search Engines Key From Tab

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know if it was default behaviour or not but until recently I could use the spacebar to search my search engines. Now it only uses tab.

So until recently I could put "yt news" into the omnibar and it'd search youtube for news. Now I have to type "yt [TAB] news"

The other way is completely ingrained in my muscle memory at this point.

I know the argument will be made that setting it to the spacebar can lead to errors where the omnibar interprets the first word of your search as a search engine keyword but this was never an issue for me as I'd set up my keywords to be unique enough for this to never happen.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought at first that Chrome forgot all my custom keywords until I found out that the shortcut has changed. Very confusing.

Turns out you can get the old behaviour back by setting the flag [`chrome://flags/#omnibox-keyword-search-button`](http://chrome://flags/#omnibox-keyword-search-button) to `Disabled`.

Props to this Redditor for finding it out: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/lilkij/custom_automatic_searches_not_working/gn4n48h

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome. Cheers!